# What does "build:" mean in the java -cp option?

Tags: java, command-line, frege

I was learning about Frege and saw this command line:

```
$ java -Xss1m -cp build:fregec.jar examples.SimpleIO
```

I've never seen that `build:` before.  What does that mean and what does it do?

More context: https://github.com/Frege/frege/issues/289

I don't see it documented in [this official article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) or when I type `java` at the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:` is the separator, so it's including `build` and `fregec.jar` on the classpath.

Looking at Frege specifically, you first use it to compile some code and create some class files in the `build` directory. For example:

```
java -Xss1m -jar fregec.jar -d build SimpleIO.fr
```

Then to run the compiled code you need both Frege itself, and the class files you just created, on the classpath:

```
java -Xss1m -cp build:fregec.jar examples.SimpleIO
```

Comment: Oh duh.  I forgot the quickstart guide had a build directory in it.  Total brain fart and I'm not used to running java from the command line.  Thanks for the help.